# react-select opened options floating css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-select

Good morning everyone,

I am working on the react-select implementation and I have a css problem when react-select is opened and is situated inside a container with overflow:auto (which I cannot change since its not created by my app). By default, options are displayed inside the container like this: 
[image]

Ideally options should just go outside the container, similar to this:
[image]

I already tried overriding /react-select/less/select' and adding some custom classes without success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You will have to provide some example. if you can create codepen that would be great.

Comment: Apparently this is a more general problem with absolute positioned elements inside of an overflow container. Same problem exist with react-autocomplete https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/issues/235

Comment: u can change default css, find in console this element and rewrite its style.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, I cannot change the container where the react-select is rendered so there is no way to modify its css.

I found the solution in using React Portals (available from the version 16.0.0).
Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component. So my options are not dependent on the container css anymore :)

This is the page that talks about this problem with react-select
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/810